# How to pass an event through classes in C#

Tags: c#

Here are 3 C# classes :

```
class StartClass
{
  event StartEvent;
  // some code
```

```
class MidClass
{
  private StartClass _startClass;
  public MidClass (StartClass startClass)
  {
    _startClass = startClass;
  }
  // some code
```

```
class EndClass
{
  private MidClass _midClass;
  public EndClass (MidClass midClass)
  {
    _midClass = midClass;
  }
  // some code

  public void OnStartEvent () 
  {
    // code to be executed on StartEvent called
  }
```

What's best way if you want to attach `EndClass.OnStartEvent` listener to `StartClass.StartEvent` event ?

I think the best way would be to create a `MidClass.StartEvent` property referencing `StartClass.StartEvent` event in order to be able to attach the listener in `EndClass` doing `_midClass.StartEvent =+ OnStartEvent;`. Am I right ? How to attach `StartClass.StartEvent` to `MidClass.StartEvent` ?

Comment: Would `MidClass` expose its `StartClass` reference publicly or not?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve, in addition to how you are trying to do it? Someone may be able to offer you a better solution.

Comment: Nope, `StartClass` is a private ref

Comment: @TanveerBadar as said in the first post, I'm trying to attach a listener declared in a class to an event declared in an other, with a third class in the middle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# an event is much like a property. It is a wrapper for a delegate. Usually we are using auto-implemented events. But we can expand them. Properties have `get` and `set` accessors. Events have `add` and `remove` accessors.

```cs
class MidClass
{
    private readonly StartClass _startClass;
    public MidClass (StartClass startClass)
    {
        _startClass = startClass;
    }

    public event EventHandler StartEvent
    {
        add => _startClass.StartEvent += value;
        remove => _startClass.StartEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

Here, we create a `StartEvent` in `MidClass` that is a wrapper for the corresponding event in `StartClass`. `StartClass.StartEvent` must be public.

The advantage of this approach is that an event handler subscribing to `MidClass.StartEvent` will directly be attached to `StartClass.StartEvent`, with no intermediate call occurring when the event is risen.

One word to naming. Methods named `OnEventName` are usually used to raise events, while methods named `PublisherName_EventName` are used for event handlers.

```cs
class StartClass
{
    public event EventHandler StartEvent;

    private virtual void OnStartEvent()
    {
        StartEvent?Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class EndClass
{
    private MidClass _midClass;

    public EndClass (MidClass midClass)
    {
        _midClass = midClass;
        _midClass.StartEvent += MidClass_StartEvent;
    }

    private void MidClass_StartEvent (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to be executed when StartEvent is triggered
    }
}
```

Comment: An elegant alternative, and it definitely has less overhead than my suggestion. Note, though, that StartClass is not entirely hidden here: The `sender` argument of `EventHandler` will contain a reference to `StartClass`, not to `MidClass` (which might or might not be what OP wants).

Comment: You can choose to deviate from this (sender, e) pattern and use e.g. `Action<T>`  or a custom  delegate instead.

Comment: Thank you fo your reply. I definitely like this approach
```C#
    public event EventHandler StartEvent
    {
        add => _startClass.StartEvent += value;
        remove => _startClass.StartEvent -= value;
    }
```
I'm in a case where it is preferable not to modify `StartClass` which is used elsewhere, add a virtual `StartClass.OnStartEvent` could break something.

Btw gg for the naming point

Answer (score 2):

> I think the best way would be to create a `MidClass.StartEvent` property referencing `StartClass.StartEvent` event in order to be able to attach the listener in `EndClass` doing `_midClass.StartEvent =+ OnStartEvent`;. Am I right?

If you want to keep the reference to `StartClass` a private implementation detail of `MidClass`: Yes, implementing a "proxy" `StartEvent` in MidClass is the right way to do it.

> How to attach StartClass.StartEvent to MidClass.StartEvent ?

By attaching a listener to `_startClass.StartEvent` which just raises the corresponding event in `MidClass`:

```
class MidClass
{
    public event EventHandler StartEvent;

    private readonly StartClass _startClass;
    public MidClass(StartClass startClass)
    {
        _startClass = startClass;
        _startClass.StartEvent += (sender, e) => this.StartEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that I also added the `readonly` modifier to `_startClass`: If the value of `_startClass` changes during the lifetime of `MidClass`, you need to detach your event handler from the old reference and attach it to the new reference.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I'll try this, thank you !